RewriteRule in .htaccess does not work as intended and explained on the internet
I have this website where when I want to go from index.php to leistungen.php the url should be ...website/leistungen. The problem is I can't get the .php away. The website is being hosted on Hostinger.
To achieve this I tried several different ways on how the RewriteRule is written. The only thing that seems to work partly is the following:
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

I also tried but it didn't work:
Rewrite Engine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Just to name a few. Sadly I haven't saved the code which I tried out.
I say partly because now you can manually access ...website/leistungen but if you click on a href redirecting to the site it always goes to ...website/leistungen.php.
Different ways for the href's have been:
leistungen, /leistungen, ...website/leistungen
There is one way to make it work but it is kind of dirty in my eyes. On the Hostinger website I can create a redirect rule from ...website/leistungen.php to ...website/leistungen. But as I said before I don't want to do it this way as it would mean that I have to input every website for http and https manualy and this is just too much work.
Instructions which I tried:
StackOverflow: url-rewrite-not-working-on-htaccess
Alexican: how-to-remove-php-extensions-with-htaccess
Tried to solve the error with the help of perplexity.ai
Had extensive discussions with the Support from Hostinger.

"but if you click on a href redirecting to the site it always goes to ...website/leistungen.php." - presumably, because the latter is what you output as the content of the href attribute of that link in the first place? Your link should of course point to /website/leistungen now, and not /website/leistungen.php. For outside URLs that you are not in control of, an additional rewrite might get implemented - but your own links should point to the "correct" target to begin with, so that those do not require a redirect all the time.

yeah thats clear, the href is implemented correctly.

Have you tested this in a private browser window, to make sure you are not getting fooled by an already cached, faulty redirect? Because with the latter two versions you have shown, I can't see how those could possibly cause an external redirect (unless you are doing other URL rewriting after those two snippets, which could again interfere?)
